# Ruby Koans - Why are repetition operators called "greedy"

Tags: ruby

Ran across this in the koans. `about_regular_expressions.rb`

```
# THINK ABOUT IT:
#
# We say that the repetition operators above are "greedy."
#
# Why?
```

When I plug "We say that the repetition operators above are "greedy." Why?" into stackoverflow I get zero results. That hasn't been the case for anything else I've plugged in from koans, figured this should be here for completeness. :)

Comment: Not specific to Ruby, the answer linked above also applies here.